# Whether the recursive function is used correctly

Tags: python, function, recursion

I made these functions. As you can see, it is a recursive function. I think that if there is an error in `try:`, I wrote the code that goes back to `try:`  after refreshing.
In the end, is the code waiting for the element of `bg_wrap` to appear?

```
def time_wait():
    try:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60, poll_frequency=0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'bg_wrap')))
    except:
        driver.refresh()
        time_wait()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically not a good idea to put a recursive call into an error handler.  If there really is an error in the code, then you'll just recurse more and more deeply.

I'd prefer something like:

```
def time_wait():
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            WebDriverWait(....)
            break
        except:
            driver.refresh()
```

Even better would be to keep track of how many times you've ended up in the error handler, and once it reaches a certain count, to just accept the error.

```
def time_wait():
    error_count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            WebDriverWait(....)
            break
        except:
            error_count += 1
            if error_count >= 5: 
                 raise
            driver.refresh()
```

Comment: I'll think about the two answers.Thank you:)